# header("Location:... - как правильно?

Tags: php, http, синтаксис, http-заголовки

Чуток странноватый вопрос, но я спрашиваю потому что хочу знать и понять. Какая разница между такими записями? Как правильно (по научному) <s>писать</s> записать строчку?

```
header("Location:/user.php?uid=$uid");

header("Location: /user.php?uid=$uid");

header("Location:user.php?uid=$uid");

header("Location: user.php?uid=$uid");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Между `Location:` и `url` лучше ставить пробел для большей читабельности. 
Разница между `/user.php` и `user.php` в том что если в начале стоит `/` то файл будет искаться в корне проекта, а если без то в папке в которой находится текущий скрипт.

Comment: "Разница между /user.php и user.php в том что если в начале стоит / то файл будет искаться в корне проекта, а если без то в папке в которой находится текущий скрипт." - что-то я протупил по этому поводу. Это ж абсолютный и относительный пути.

Comment: А еще правильнее будет указывать полный путь `header("Location: http://user.php?uid=$uid");`

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy Ну так абсолютный начинается с корня, а относительный с текущего url

Comment: "указывать полный путь" - эээ, но это может повлиять на переносимость кода. Хотя я незн. как оно будет работать с httpS:// Работу с сертификатами мы еще не изучали.

Comment: @Venta "указывать полный путь" как по мне не лучшая идея. Что будет если нужно будет сменить домен? Или при копировании на локальный компьютер для разработки придется перекрыть ip сервера локальным ip в `/etc/hosts` для того что бы сайт работал. И как говорил @root_x Povierennyy если нужно будет перейти на `https` то на всех таких ссылках нужно будет сменить протокол.

Comment: ну ссылки сменить можно и внести ищменения в /etc/hosts можно, но зачем создавать эти проблемы? и "...  header("Location: http://user.php?uid=$uid");" - это аж никак не полный путь. кажется, здесь имени домена не хватает.