# Переадресация со страницы, если не совпадают данные пользователя в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно сделать так, что бы когда обычный пользователь пытался перейти на страницу, на которую он не должен попадать, его переадресовывало на главную страницу `../`

У меня есть скрипт, который не показывает пользователю кнопку `<a href="../admin"><button class="green">Панель администратора</button></a>`, если в бд, в столбце `role` у него не указано `admin`.

Возможно ли как то переделать этот скрипт, что бы он по такому же принципу не пускал обычных пользователей на определённую страницу?

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'storas_calendar');
            $results = $connect->query("SELECT `role` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user']['id']."' LIMIT 1");
            $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
            if ($row['role']=="admin"){
                   echo '<a href="../admin"><button class="green">Панель администратора</button></a>';
            }
            else {
                echo '';
            }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598894/headerlocation-как-правильно вам поможет

Comment: @realHikkan Блин, и ведь простенькая задачка то. Но таааааак лень. Тут и про PDO надо рассказать, и про сессии, и про функции. Просто посмотрел все Ваши предыдущие вопросы. Вроде и подсказывают Вам правильно, но Вы как-то не в том направлении двигаетесь. Всё гораздо проще. Если будет желание - пишите в чат или в вотсап. Постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Более разумно было-бы использование if в switch, где нужные кейсы были под нужными условиями а default был бы их редиректом...

Answer (score 0):

как вариант во втором кейсе прописать:

```
echo '<script>location.assign(\'http://login/\');</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `else { echo ''; }` не надо=)

А далее вот так по аналогии:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'storas_calendar');
$results = $connect->query("SELECT `role` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user']['id']."' LIMIT 1");
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();

if ($row['role'] != "admin"){
  header("Location: ../"); // Редирект
  die(); // Прекращаем работу скрипта, всё что ниже - не выполнится
}
```